# How to fix the "SIGSEGV" error in C code?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void bubblesort(int a[],int num) {
    int temp;
    int count=0;

    for(int i=0;i<num-1;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<num-i-1;j++) {
            if(a[i]>a[j]) {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
                count++;
            }
         }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
}
int main() {
    int i,j,n=5;
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5};

    bubblesort(arr,n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would also add a little more explanation in the body of the post, such as where the error is raised, etc.

Comment: Cannot reproduce - and note the array is already sorted so `count` remains `0`. But I would change the inner loop to be `for(int j = i + 1; j < num; j++)`

Comment: Why do you declare the variables `i` and `j` in `main()`? They're not used.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a pretty standard implementation of bubble sort. However, there's one mistake.

```c
if(a[i]>a[j]) {
    temp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[j];
    a[j]=temp;
    count++;
}
```

`i` should be `j+1`.

Additionally, `j` should start at 0:

`for(int j = 0; j < num - i - 1; j++) {`

For reference:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: All of them should be changed? Can you explain why?

Comment: That link, is not the same code. Here, `j` already starts at `i + 1`.